# Check if preceding objects exist

Tags: python

I need to write a method in Python to check that if a key is provided by the user, the preceding key must also be provided.

Example: If the user provides a list `['id_4','id_5','id_6'...]`, this will throw an error because the user did not provide the preceding keys, `'id_1','id_2','id_3'`.

A valid list: `['id_1','id_2','id_3','id_4','id_5','id_6']`

An invalid list: `['id_6']` (missing id_1 to id_5)

Note: this could be done with a dictionary or set, just curious if there are more elegant solutions out there.

Comment: Get the first key in the list, and check if the number is 1.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: So the user always has to provide id_1 to id_n. Why not just let them provide n?

Comment: I tried getting the last element then checking the integer value to see if the list size matches the value. But this is a high-level check and doesn't meet the current requirement for individual values `id_1, id_2...`

Comment: @mkrieger1 that doesn't work because this is a checker and is meant to throw an error if isn't provided! It doesn't do anything else beside that.

Comment: Ok... so why not just `for i, x in enumerate(sorted(lst)): if x != f'id_{i}': raise ValueError` (maybe without sorting)? The possibilities are open-ended and that's why I think this question is basically opinion-based.

Comment: Is the order also important? Can you have duplicates?

Comment: I would create a set with the numbers with `data = ['id_1','id_2','id_3','id_4','id_5','id_6']
ids = set(int(value.split('_')[1]) for value in data)`. Then a simple `print(max(ids) == len(ids))` will give you the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the preceding key must be in the list for each key, by recurrence this means that all key from the start must be present.

I think an ideal tool to validate this is a `set`:

```
def valid(l):
    return set(l) == {f'id_{i}' for i in range(1, len(l)+1)}
    # if you prefer to throw an exception, use
    # assert set(l) == {f'id_{i}' for i in range(1, len(l)+1)}

valid(['id_4','id_5','id_6'])
# False

valid(['id_1','id_2','id_3','id_4'])
# True
```

###### IDs in order

If the IDs also need to be sorted, you can compare the pairs. For this [`itertools.pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise) can help (*NB. `pairwise` requires python ≥ 3.10, for previous versions, check the recipe in the doc*)

```
def valid(l):
    return (l and l[0] == 'id_1' 
            and all(a+1 == b for a,b in
            pairwise(int(x.rpartition('_')[-1]) 
            for x in l))
            )

valid(['id_4','id_5','id_6'])
# False

valid(['id_1','id_2','id_3','id_4'])
# True

valid(['id_1','id_3','id_2'])
# False
```

Comment: This is very close! How would you keep track of which `id-#` is missing? I know this wasn't asked earlier but it's a nice feature to have.

Comment: @danynl with the sets, `S.difference(l)`

Answer (score 0):

### Cyclic sort if no duplicates are allowed

If you cannot use additional space (sets, dictionaries), then you can in-place sort, via cyclic sort.
This will be o(n) complexity with o(1) space.

Because element 1 -> n must be in a list of size n, we can assume if an item is greater than n, the list is not valid.

Then we can try and check for duplicates.

By the end, all elements 1-> n must be in the list of size n with no duplicates which satisfies your requirement. This solution is better than the dictionary/set approach as it uses no additional space.

```
def cyclicSort(l):
    def getNumFromID(id):
        return int(id[3:])


    i = 0

    while i < len(l):
        correctIndex = getNumFromID(l[i]) - 1
        if correctIndex > len(l):
            return False

        
        if i != correctIndex:
            numberAtCorrectIndex = getNumFromID(l[correctIndex])
            if numberAtCorrectIndex > len(l):
                return False



            if numberAtCorrectIndex != l[i]:
                if l[correctIndex] == l[i]:
                    # duplicate found
                    return False
                #swap the numbers after confirming neither are out of bounds
                l[correctIndex], l[i] = l[i], l[correctIndex]

        else:
            i += 1


    return True


print(cyclicSort(['id_1','id_2','id_3','id_4','id_5','id_6']))
print(cyclicSort(['id_1']))
print(cyclicSort(['id_6']))
print(cyclicSort(['id_2','id_3','id_4','id_5','id_6','id_1']))
print(cyclicSort(['id_1','id_2','id_3','id_4','id_5','id_5']))
```

### Sorted list approach checking preceding elements##

If the list is already sorted, then

```
def checkPreceding(l):
    id = 1
    baseStr = "id_"

    for idToCheck in l:
        if idToCheck != baseStr + str(id):
            return False
        id += 1

    return True



print(checkPreceding(['id_1','id_2','id_3','id_4','id_5','id_6']))
print(checkPreceding(['id_1']))
print(checkPreceding(['id_6']))
```

If the list is sorted, it's better to use `checkPreceding` approach since you will only need O(1) space.
However, if it is not sorted, you can use a dictionary/set for o(n) complexity with o(n) space or cyclic sort for o(1) space.